# How to parse date YYYYMMDDHHMMSSUTC

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

For example, parsing `20150828020000UTC`? Haven't found anything resembling. `DateTime.ParseExact` doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: can you show your code and the data you are imputtng/trying to parse?

Comment: What's not working about `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string timeString = "20150828020000UTC";
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss'UTC'", culture);
```

Comment: If the `UTC` is included, as the opening post seems to assume, you'd need to specify the format string as `"yyyyMMddHHmmss'UTC'"`

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh thanks lot ... :)  Updated